# FileUpload keeps uploading the same file

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, file-upload, webforms

Simple FileUpload example won't work properly on any browser. Instead what it does when the button is clicked is it keeps uploading the same file over and over again.

It seems like this only happens when the file being uploaded is saved under the project path. If I try to save the file on Desktop for example, it works fine.

HTML

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
</div>
</form>
```

C#

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        string path = Server.MapPath("/Files/");
        FileUpload1.SaveAs(path + FileUpload1.FileName);
    }
}
```

Comment: @YvetteColomb FileUpload has its own selector?

Comment: @YvetteColomb it's not a particular file and how it behaves is completely random. sometimes it uploads just once as it supposed to, most of the time it uploads 10+ times and once it stopped after a while and threw an exception (SEH)